# Did All for one give his ability to Tomura?

Tags: my-hero-academia

In My Hero Academia, after the Showdown between All for One and all might, One for all is finally defeated.

But when he was arrested, All for One said the words :

> As a teacher, I win, as my pupil is ready. (paraphrasing)

While it most certainly concerns the growth of Tomura, both as a leader, and as a villain, I am left wondering if it implied something more.

Did All for One pass on his ability to Tomura, the same All Might passed his ability to Izuku ?

We already know that All for One is able to give and take other's ability at will, I don't think it would be far fetched to think that this could apply to All for One itself.

On a story viewpoint, it would make Tomura a much stronger foe, and make him even more of a parallel to Izuku.

So, did Tomura inherit from All for One ? (is there any specification, from Canon, or author, hinting or stating that he did/did not ?)

Comment: As of chapter 181, there is no way to know yet and we could speculate anything. Personally I believe he just meant that the brainwashing of Tomura is complete.

Comment: Still nothing about it. I guess, only time will tell. So, there is no answer to this question at the moment.

Comment: Now that the manga has gone so far ahead uptill the 276th chapter, i'm pretty sure this question has been answered in i guess the 270th chapter or...maybe near 268 something...

Answer (score 1):

In the anime? No. But in the manga? Yes:

> Shigiraki gains All for one and goes ballistic trying to get Midoriya's power, we see him use radio waves on Endeavour, who cant speak on the earpiece anymore. He'll likely try and use more powers later, unless he really does get beaten as chapter 280 shows